# [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package ' express'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error when I run my server like this with command `node backend/server.js`

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package ' express' imported from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\web\Amazona\backend\server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed express?

You can install it via NPM

Type this in your cmd
`npm i exress`

Comment: thank you,i resolved it

Comment: Can you click the arrow on my Answer so it turns green so people know the right answer?